# Catch Motion End event in Leaflet Motion Plugin

Tags: javascript, animation, events, leaflet

I ma currently using leaflet, leaflet motion plugin for animating the polyline.

Now I need to show a popup after the motion animation is completed.

How can I catch the motion end event.

From the docs, I can see L.Motion.Event.Ended event will be fired after the motion end.

But I am unable to get this motion end event.

Can anyone help in catching the motion end event in leaflet motion.

Answer (score 2):

Just figured this out.  Once you create the motion object, you can a listener to it like this:

```
var route = L.motion.polyline(pol, {
    color: "steelblue",// + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16),
    weight:4
  }, 
  {          
    auto:false,
    duration:this.route_speed
  },
  {
    removeOnEnd: true,
    icon: L.divIcon({
      className: 'custom-div-icon',
      html: "<i class='fas fa-map-pin' style='color:red; font-size: 20px;'></i>",
      iconSize: [30, 42],
      iconAnchor: [5, 20]
    })
  }).addTo(this.map);

this.routes.push(route);

route.on('motion-started', (e) => {
  console.log("START")
})

route.on('motion-ended', (e) => {
  console.log("END")
})
```